# C++ srand() function

Tags: c++, srand

Can someone explain what `srand` does exactly. I understand that it relates to the function rand and the value fed into the `srand` function is a seed value, but how exactly does this seed value affect the `rand` function?

Comment: Have you looked on the many available c++ sites like cppreference.com and cplusplus.com?

Comment: yes!  I was just confused about how the seed value affected rand itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `srand` with a particular argument, subsequent calls to `rand` will produce exactly identical sequences. So you can use `srand` to allow users to e.g. exactly reproduce the results of an algorithm that uses random numbers. For example, on my C,

```
rand: 16807
rand: 282475249
rand: 1622650073

srand(3)
rand: 50421
rand: 847425747
rand: 572982925

srand(3)
rand: 50421
rand: 847425747
rand: 572982925
```

Notice that the second sequence and third sequence are identical.

If you are asking what exact numeric relationship the seed has with the following random number, it is generally irrelevant; if you really need to know, you will need to know the exact pseudo-random number generation algorithm used: different C compilers are free to use different algorithms, as the algorithm is not defined in the C language specification.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implement in **windows** platform:

```
static UINT32 next = 1;

int __cdecl rand(void)
{
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    /* return (unsigned int)(next / 65536) % 32768;*/
    return (UINT32)(next>>16) & RAND_MAX;
}

void __cdecl srand(unsigned int seed)
{
    /* And you *should* get a warning if sizes dont match
     */
    next = seed;
}
```

So `srand` just to set the seed of the random to make following `rand` call generate the same output.